# Download Java EE API JARs as OSGI bundles

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, osgi

Is there a place where I can download Java EE API JARs as OSGi bundles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of anywhere where you can do that, but you can wrap the jars and deploy them as bundles with the [wrap scheme](http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.2/deploy_osgi/DeployJar-Wrap.html).

So the command that you would want to use to pull them from maven and wrap them as bundles would be `osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:javax/javaee-api/6.0`.

Comment: I'm so glad more people are aware of `wrap:`. It's the cleanest way to wrap non-OSGi jars as bundles.

Comment: Completely agree with Jon7 and Tony, why hold your own custom versions or hunt for obscure repos, when wrapping at runtime is so quick.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Geronimo produces API jars for the Java EE packages and they are all (at least all the ones I've used) OSGi bundles. They are all installed in maven central. You can search for them in maven central [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Corg.apache.geronimo.specs) and either download them for use outside maven, or you can add the dependency to your pom and get them that way.