# OSGI bundle , not able to resolve javax.servlet classes

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I am trying to build an OSGI bundle of a class which imports the following:

```
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyContent;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport;
```

I am trying to build this as a plugin project in Eclipse. I added j2ee jar which resolved the errors but export as a plugin fails.

I also didn't want to add the j2ee jar to it since there might me mismatch in the OSGi container. What'es the best way to resolve this? I am new to OSGI..

Comment: What's the OSGi container you use? It could be easier if you registered the OSGi container in Eclipse so its libraries are available to the project and not bundled in the OSGi Application. You may also find the article [Simple form-based JSF 2 web application with Eclipse IDE and WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile](http://jaceklaskowski.pl/wiki/Simple_form-based_JSF_2_web_application_with_Eclipse_IDE_and_WebSphere_Application_Server_V8.5_Liberty_Profile) useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are bundles available from Geronimo and ServiceMix which provide the Servlet API. Though you probably still need a web-container to run your OSGi-Web application. So how is your container setup to look like?

For the OSGi Containers there are [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/) and [Eclipse Virgo](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/). Both of them provide also a Web-Container. If you want to setup your own Container you might want to take a look at [Pax-Web](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxweb/Pax+Web). This one also provides the needed Servlet APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a bundlified version of the j2ee.jar for use in an OSGi container. If this is not the case, just [bundle it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277172/download-java-ee-api-jars-as-osgi-bundles).